# $y(t)=-(V+2)e^{-3t}+(V+3)e^{-2t}$ nonnegative for which $V$?

Tags: inequality

From $(V+3)e^{-3t}-(V+2)e^{-2t}\geq 0$, we get $(V+3)e^{-t} \geq V+2$. The answer in the textbook says $V\geq -3$. How does one come to this?

Context: this is problem 2.2.9 of Braun's Differential Equations and Their Applications.

> Let $y(t)$ be the solution of the initial-value problem $$y''+5y'+6y=0; \ y(0)=1,\ y'(0)=V.$$ For what values of V does $y(t)$ remain nonnegative for all $t\geq0$.

**Edit.**
After @NeatMath pointed out in the comment, I saw that I misread my own notes. :)

We have $y(t)=c_1e^{-3t}+c_2e^{-2t}$.

Inserting the initial conditions, we have $y(0)=c_1+c_2=1$ and $-3c_1-2c_2=V$. Substituting $c_1=1-c_2$, into the first equation, we have
\begin{align}
-3(1-c_2) -2c_2 &= V \\
-3+c_2 &= V \\
c_2 &= V+3 \\
c_1&= 1-c_2 = 1-(V+3) = -(V+2).
\end{align}
Hence $y(t)=-(V+2)e^{-3t} + (V+3)e^{-2t}$.

Comment: Your solution is wrong. It should be $$y(t) = -(V+2) e^{-3t} + (V+3) e^{-2t}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^t(V+3)\geqslant V+2 \Rightarrow V \geqslant \frac{2-3e^t}{e^t-1}, \forall t>0 \Rightarrow V \geqslant \lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{2-3e^t}{e^t-1} = -3$.

On the other hand if $V\geqslant -3$, then $e^t(V+3)\geqslant V+2.$

Comment: How do you know that $V\geq \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{2-3e^t}{e^t - 1}$? That is why do you think the limit will give an underbound?

Comment: You can take limit if both sides of the inequality have limits. In this case, yes they do (LHS is a constant).

Answer (score 2):

Using $y(t) = -(V + 2)e^{-3t} + (V + 3)e^{-2t}$, as pointed out in the comments:

$$y(t)\geq 0$$

$$(V + 3)e^{-2t} - (V+2)e^{-3t} \geq 0$$

$$(V + 3)e^{-2t} \geq (V+2)e^{-3t}$$

Dividing by the positive value $e^{-2t}$:

$$V + 3\geq (V + 2)e^{-t}$$

Here, we will split into cases:

Case 1: $V < -2$

If this is the case, then $V+ 2$ is negative. Dividing by this value:

$$\frac{V+ 3}{V + 2}\leq e^{-t}$$

$$1 + \frac{1}{V + 2}\leq e^{-t}$$

$e^{-t}$ may become arbitrarily close to $0$, and $V$ is independent of $t$, so we must have:

$$1 + \frac{1}{V + 2}\leq 0$$

$$-\frac{1}{V + 2}\geq 1$$

$$V + 2\geq -1$$

$$V\geq -3$$

Thus, $-3\leq V<-2$ works.

Case 2: $V\geq -2$

$V + 2$ is now positive. Dividing by this value:

$$\frac{V + 3}{V + 2}\geq e^{-t}$$

$$1 + \frac{1}{V + 2}\geq e^{-t}$$

Since $t\geq 1$, $e^{-t}\leq 1$. Combining this with $\frac{1}{V+ 2}>0$, we see that this inequality is always true, and thus $V\geq -2$ works.

Combining both cases, we see that $\boxed{V\geq -3}$